# Git ignores directories with ignored files

Tags: git

I want to add files from src/mainsrc directory, so I run `git add src/mainsrc/*`

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
src/mainsrc/main.o
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

This is no good.  I want to add everything in src/mainsrc *except* the ignored files.

I don't want to use -f, because I don't want to add .o files.  I don't want to go through adding all of the files in src/mainsrc by hand, because I might miss something.  `git add src/mainsrc/*.cpp` only overs .cpp files.  What should I do?

Comment: Perhaps main.o is considered explicitly specified: "The git add command will not add ignored files by default. If any ignored files were explicitly specified on the command line, git add will fail with a list of ignored files. Ignored files reached by directory recursion or filename globbing performed by Git (quote your globs before the shell) will be silently ignored. The git add command can be used to add ignored files with the -f (force) option."  --man git add

Comment: If you just want to ignore `.o` files in `src/mainsrc`, why not modify your `.gitignore` file to ignore `src/mainsrc/*.o` ?

Comment: Actually, it was already in the .gitignore file.  The problem was that nothing else was being added either.

Comment: the `.gitignore` file was ignore all files under `src/mainsrc`. I think the OP wants to ignore just the `.o` files, in which case my solution will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git add src/mainsrc`

Turns out, any ignored files that are explicitly named cause the add to fail, and any files included by `*` that are not in a subdirectory are considered explicitly added.

> The git add command will not add ignored files by default. If any ignored files were explicitly specified on the command line, git add will fail with a list of ignored files. Ignored files reached by directory recursion or filename globbing performed by Git (quote your globs before the shell) will be silently ignored. The git add command can be used to add ignored files with the -f (force) option.

--[git add man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore all non-object files in the `src/mainsrc/` directory, simply modify your `.gitignore` file to be `src/mainsrc/*.o` instead of `src/mainsrc/`. Then you can simply type: `git add src/mainsrc/`, which will stage all of the non object files.